# Line bearing for wind direction for plume of smoke QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, bearing

I'm trying to draw a line representing direction of a plume of smoke for an emergency planning scenario in QGIS. The line needs to be 5km in length and have a bearing of 85 degrees. The closest I have found to achieve this is the CAD like drawing plug-in but this uses angles rather than compass bearings, so 180 degrees would be pointing west rather than south and vice verse.

Is there a tool to draw lines using compass angles and ideally length?

Thanks.

Comment: it is easy with Python in the Python Console

Comment: I'm not au fait with Python yet, it's a learning curve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Azimuth and Distance plug-in will do this.